# how can i write a query to get in between values from a column by not mentioning the complete string

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

for example ive got values like

```
date column
Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)
Mar 04 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)
Mar 05 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)
Mar 08 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)
```

i want the values between mar 03 2021 to mar 05 2021

is there any way that i can get those values without mentioning the whole string and only by mentioning the date ive tried trim and like but they are good for getting one value but i want n number of values between those days ignoring the rest of the string in query

Comment: plsql <> mysql.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: So these "dates" are actually held as strings?

Comment: yes "Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)" this whole part is under a single string variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that **all** values share the same date format in the first 11 characters of that column, you'd *convert* it to a date value (using the `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format mask) and compare it to wanted `date` values.

Sample data in lines #1 - 6; query begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)' from dual union all
  3     select 'Mar 04 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)'   from dual union all
  4     select 'Mar 05 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)'   from dual union all
  5     select 'Mar 08 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from test
  9  where to_date(substr(col, 1, 11), 'Mon dd yyyy', 'nls_date_language = english')
 10    between date '2021-03-03' and date '2021-03-05';

COL
-----------------------------------------------
Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)
Mar 04 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)
Mar 05 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Between" Operator in sql.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: you didn't got my point actually i have to get that information by just using the date part like "Mar 03 2021" And "Mar 05 2021" not the complete string "Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)" And "Mar 05 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)"

Answer (score 0):

in PL/SQL you may do date query like this :
today is: 15/03/2021

select * from table
where date_column between  to_date('03/03/2021','DD/MM/YYYY')
and to_date('06/03/2021','DD/MM/YYYY')

Answer (score 0):

The first thing be would to fix the data model, even if this just parameter somewhere. Beyond that however I do not think you have indicated the issue you are having other than spiting up a string, and relative poor job even of just that. But perhaps you are looking for something like:

```
with junk_string (js)  as 
     ( select 'Mar 03 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)' from dual union all
       select 'Mar 04 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)'   from dual union all
       select 'Mar 05 2021 22:00:00 GMT(india standard time)'   from dual union all
       select 'Mar 08 2021 21:00:00 GMT(central daylight time)' from dual 
     ) 
   , junk_set( junk_date, junk_rest) as 
     ( select cast( to_timestamp (substr(js, 1, instr(js, 'GMT') - 1)  
                                 , 'Mon dd yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
                                 )  
                    at time zone 'GMT' as date 
                  )
             , substr(js, instr(js, 'GMT') +3) 
          from junk_string
     )
select * 
  from junk_set 
 where junk_date >= date '2021-03-03' 
   and junk_date <  date '2021-03-05';
```